# How to get a map of filename without extension to file contents from a directory path in configuration.nix?

Tags: nixos, nix

Basically, I want to pull [my `config.programs.config.alias` entries](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/blob/90b8dc3fcd4161735ff402d8bc98ff29273e742d/configuration.nix#L298-306) into separate `.bash` files and read them dynamically when building the configuration. A representative subset of the current configuration:

```
{
  programs.git = {
    config = {
      alias = {
        aliases = "!git config --get-regexp '^alias\.' | cut --delimiter=. --fields 2-";
        git = "!git";
        st = "status";
      };
    };
  };
}
```

All of the `!git` entries would be better off as separate shell scripts. That way I can lint, format, and run them to verify that they work before integrating them in the Git aliases configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotated version of the [solution so far](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/commit/175621227666a5722be1e672db1643336b97106e):

```
{
  config.git.config.alias =
    (
      lib.attrsets.mergeAttrsList ( # Change from a list of attribute sets to a single attribute set
        map (
          path: {
            # Create a [filename without extension as alias name] to [alias value] attribute set
            "${lib.removeSuffix ".bash" (baseNameOf path)}" =
              "!\"" # `!`denotes that this alias runs a command rather than a Git subcommand; quote to simplify escaping
              + builtins.replaceStrings ["\n"] ["; "] ( # Change from readable multi-line scripts to a single line
                lib.escape ["\"" "\\"] ( # Escape backslash and double quotes to fit Git configuration language
                  lib.removeSuffix "\n" ( # Remove newline at EOF
                    builtins.readFile path
                  )
                )
              )
              + "\"";
          }
        ) (
          lib.filesystem.listFilesRecursive ./includes/git-aliases
        )
      )
    )
    // {
      st = "status";
    };
}
```

It seems to work for all my aliases, including those with single and double quotes, backslashes, and newlines. Hopefully someone else comes up with something simpler, but this'll do for now.